# 'dict object' has no attribute 'address_prefixes'

Tags: ansible

Unable to get address_prefixes for output. Getting error, 'dict object' has no attribute 'address_prefixes'. {{ prefix_list['name'] }} seems like it works but {% for prefix in prefix_list['address_prefixes'] %} throws the error

Task:

```
  tasks:
    - name: Gather Junos prefix-lists
      junipernetworks.junos.junos_prefix_lists:
        state: gathered
      register: prefix_response

    - name: parse info
      set_fact:
        test: "{{ prefix_response.gathered }}"

    - copy:
        content: >-
          {% for prefix_list in test %}
          - prefix_list_name: {{ prefix_list['name'] }}
            prefix:
            {% for prefix in prefix_list['address_prefixes'] %}
              - {{ prefix }}
            {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        dest: output.yaml
```

prefix_response:

```
[
        {
            "address_prefixes": [
                "10.0.0.0/8",
                "172.16.0.0/12",
                "192.168.0.0/16"
            ],
            "name": "test1"
        },
        {
            "address_prefixes": [
                "1.1.1.1/32",
                "2.2.2.2/32",
                "3.3.3.3/32"
            ],
            "name": "test2"
        }
]
```

Expecting:

```
- prefix_list_name: TEST1
  prefix:
    - 10.0.0.0/8
    - 172.16.0.0/12
    - 192.168.0.0/16

- prefix_list_name: TEST2
  prefix:
    - 1.1.1.1/32
    - 2.2.2.2/32
    - 3.3.3.3/32
```

Comment: You reference the attribute *gathered* ``test: "{{ prefix_response.gathered }}"``. But there is no attribute *gathered* in the variable ``prefix_response`` you posted. [edit] the question and make it [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the fancy loop vars [keep it simple stupid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). The task below

```yaml
    - copy:
        content: |-
          {% for i in test %}
          - prefix_list_name: {{ i.name|upper }}
            prefix:
          {% for j in i.address_prefixes %}
              - {{ j }}
          {% endfor %}

          {% endfor %}
        dest: output.yaml
      vars:
        test: "{{ prefix_response.gathered }}"
```

creates the file

```yaml
shell> cat output.yaml
- prefix_list_name: TEST1
  prefix:
    - 10.0.0.0/8
    - 172.16.0.0/12
    - 192.168.0.0/16

- prefix_list_name: TEST2
  prefix:
    - 1.1.1.1/32
    - 2.2.2.2/32
    - 3.3.3.3/32
```

Comment: Still getting "The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'address_prefixes". Using ansible 2.9.27 and python version 3.6.8